# Generate random points satisfying linear constraints

Tags: sampling, constraints, python

In my problem, I have a vector **x** of len N. Where each element **xij** is the price of the product i in the country j. Let's say that I have 100 products and 20 countries, so N=100x20=2000.

The solution of X is subject to a set of linear constraints. For instance, minimum/maximum price for each product and maximum difference allowed for the same product between countries. Therefore, I can define the constraints as a matrix **Ax<=b**

I guess the problem would be like sampling points from a space bounded by hyperplanes defined by the constraints.

Assuming that the problem has multiple feasible solutions. How can I generate random points (solutions of the vector **x**) that satisfy the constraints? There is any python library that could help me with that?

I tried with https://github.com/python-constraint/python-constraint, but it seems that because the number of solutions is very large, the algorithm gets stuck at some point or takes a long time to return the solution.

Comment: have you tried using the rejection method?

Comment: @user619894 I tried generating random values of X satisfying min/max constraint, and afterwards filtering the ones that satisfy the other constraints. The problem is that the process is extremely slow because of this way is very difficult to satisfy all the constraints at the same time. I have a third type of constraint based on the hierarchy of prices (product A can't have a higher price than product B) that I ommited in the description of the problem by simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

As @user619894 suggested, I would also have tried it with rejection method.
In your answer, you state that this process is slow, I think you mean it takes long until you have "enough" points, i.e. many generated points get rejected.
You further state you have implemented Min-Max condition for the components of the vector. Do you "update" them? By this I mean, assume you have condition $1 \leq a \leq 10$ and $3 \leq b \leq 10$ (Min-Max price) and $|a-b| \leq 2$. Assume that you sampled $a=3$. Then you could update the condition for $b$ to $3\leq b \leq5$.

The problem with rejection is, you are essentially trying to hit a dartboard with a blind shot, and of course the probability of hitting gets smaller the bigger the room is.

The only way I see to higher the success rate is to modify the inequalities, trying to eliminate variables.

(Sorry, this would fit better as a comment, but I cannot comment, I do not have enough reputation.)